# angularjs calling select on corresponding HTMLinput doesn't highlight cell contents if value comes from ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to select (highlight) the text in an input element whose value comes from a model, but it doesn't seem to work.

The element   (part of component template) in question is as follows:

```
<input id="table-input-cell" ng-blur="$ctrl.inputBlur()"
       ng-focus="$ctrl.inputFocus($event)" ng-model="$ctrl.activeText"
       class="input-cell"/>
```

The controller function looks like this:

```
ctrl.inputFocus = function(focusEvent) {
    let el = ctrl.inputView[0];
    console.log(el.constructor.name);
    console.log(`inputFocus called.  contents: ${el.value} `);
    el.select();
};
```

What I am seeing as the result on the page is this:

[image: cursor at end]

What I would like to see is this:

[image: selected stuff]

Here's the console output:

```
HTMLInputElement
budget_controller.source.js:261 inputFocus called.  contents:
```

So it looks like the problem is that the `ng-focus` may be called before the value of the input box is populated by `ng-model`, which is why `.select()` isn't highlight anything.

Or maybe it something else?  Anyway, is there some other life-cycle event in AngularJs I can use to set the selection range once the element is bound as has focus?  I don't see any thing ngBound= in the dox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event target:

```
ctrl.inputFocus = function(focusEvent) {
    ̶l̶e̶t̶ ̶e̶l̶ ̶=̶ ̶c̶t̶r̶l̶.̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶V̶i̶e̶w̶[̶0̶]̶;̶
    let el = focusEvent.target;
    console.log(el.constructor.name);
    console.log(`inputFocus called.  contents: ${el.value} `);
    el.select();
};
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/V4lL7Kq0Iq2edUulb8Jt?p=preview)